# duty cycle of a WiFi Packet

Tags: signal-analysis, bandwidth

I am doing a simple over-the-air(WiFi 802.11a) test in a shielded chamber involving one Tx and one Rx (around 5 feet).. I need to find the duty cycle given the length of the payload (in bytes), MCS etc. 
As far as I understand , duty cycle is time a device spent on channel / total time . 
I was going through this paper https://www.academia.edu/15142561/Determination_of_the_duty_cycle_of_WLAN_for_realistic_radio_frequency_electromagnetic_field_exposure_assessment
Where the paper calculates the theoretical upper limit of duty cycle for a given MCS

[image]

The payload is 1500 bytes 
Max data rate is 54 Mbps

How is the data 248 micro secs in calculations? I am thinking,it should be 222.22 micro seconds (1500*8/54 micro seconds)

can any one please let me know  about it

And If anyone has done such analysis on duty cycles , please do guide me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wifi uses OFDM, which uses symbols that can transport many bytes at once. That means you can't have arbitrary long packets, but always need to use the next multiple of a symbol duration.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus for your comment and clarification

Comment: You're welcome! You don't have to post a "thank you" comment, though – I'll take your upvote instead :)